# In R : select a value in a column by the corresponding row argument

Tags: r, dataframe

how can I select and extract a biomass value based on the name of the corresponding fish ?

```
fish_data <- data.frame(names = c("Fish_1", "Fish_2", "Fish_3", "Fish_4", "Fish_5"), 
                            biomass = c(1.532, 2.243, 1.325, 1.098, 4.347))

##################

   names biomass
1 Fish_1   1.532
2 Fish_2   2.243
3 Fish_3   1.325
4 Fish_4   1.098
5 Fish_5   4.347
```

Comment: You mean `fish_data$biomass[fish_data$names == 'Fish_1']`?

Comment: This [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=how+to+subset+rows+in+r&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&safari_group=9) for how to subset a data frame by rows may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to [Sotos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5635580/sotos)' answer, you have `dplyr::filter`.

`dplyr::filter(fish_data, names == "Fish_1")$biomass`

This method can be useful for identifying several values and/or use several logical filters, in a more concise and flexible way. For example you can retrieve all the "biomass" values of the observations having "Fish" or "fish" in their "names" with
`dplyr::filter(fish_data, stringr::str_detect(names,"Fish|fish"))$biomass`